# How to solve a session expiration issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am doing a site which has a problem with session expire issue. The form contain almost 50 input fields , I have done it in ajax. I have given the user checkings in page reload the problem is that session and cookies are setting is done when page reloads,

How can I check whether user logined or not without lossing data? Is there any ajax functions
to retain session?

Comment: Making any kind of request every couple of minutes (like an Ajax POST) should "touch" the session and prevent it from expiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solving this would be to increase the session timeout.

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '3600'); //Assign the time in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you increase the session lifetime in php.ini?
Look at options like the session.cookie_lifetime, session.gc_maxlifetime and session.cache_expire

Another option may be to make the inputs less by grouping them and only presenting the user with say 10 inputs per page. If these are submitted, present the next 10 inputs.

Yet another option may be to save the user id or session in a variable when the page is loaded, and then on submit you save the input data to a temp variable (array) if the session is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Making any kind of request every couple of minutes (like an Ajax POST) should "touch" the session and prevent it from expiring.

[Here](http://xpapad.wordpress.com/2010/06/19/preventing-session-expiration-with-ajax/) is a random code example that looks okay.